# How to use Clean code on Swift with a lot of if and else

Tags: swift

I use the following code on Swift.

```
func validateEmptyFields(){
    var errorMessage = ""
    if( nomeAnimalTextField.text == ""){
        errorMessage = "Preencha o nome do animal"
    } else if( microchipAnimalTextField.text == ""){
        errorMessage = "Preencha o microchip do animal"
    } else if( mesNascimentoTextField.text == ""){
        errorMessage = "Preencha o mês do nascimento"
    } else if( anoNascimentoTextField.text == ""){
        errorMessage = "Preencha o ano de nascimento"
    } else if( numeroAssociacaoRacaTextField.text == ""){
        errorMessage = "Preencha o número de associação da raça"
    } else if( numeroPassaporteTextField.text == ""){
        errorMessage = "Preencha o número do passaporte"
    } else if( microchipMaeTextField.text == ""){
        errorMessage = "Preencha o número do microchip da mãe"
    }
    
    if ( errorMessage == "" ) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToAnimal2", sender: nil)
    } else {
        showAlert(errorMessage)            
    }
    
}
```

It works for me, but I was trying to find a way to create a code that is more readable and clean.

Is there any suggestion to make this code more clean?

Comment: Couldn't this be in a lookup table? Does `" "` (a space) count as "empty"?

Comment: It’s pretty clean and straightforward. No one coming across that should be confused about what it does, which is good. If you wanted to compact it you could use a map to store the field names and error messages and loop over the elements of the map. Shave off 10 or so lines.

Comment: @NicholasRees How can I use a map to do that? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @tadman yes, you are right. The double quotes ("") in this case are the same as empty value

Comment: I'm asking if stuff like one or more spaces still counts as empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaner way using two parallel arrays and `firstIndex`:

```
// gather the text fields into an array
let fields = [field1, field2, field3] // or however many there are
// make a corresponding array of messages
let messages = [
  "You forgot the blorg", 
  "You forgot the zarg", 
  "You forget the firth"
] // or however many there are, one per text field

// now it's a one-liner, basically
var message : String? = nil
if let ix = fields.firstIndex { ($0.text ?? "").isEmpty } {
    message = messages[ix]
}
// all done! now check for an error message
if let message = message {
    showAlert(message)
} else {
    // no issues, valid, do the segue
}
```

(Note: follow my example and use `nil`, not a magic value like `""`, to indicate that there is no issue.)

---

**EDIT** It has been suggested in a comment that it might be better to demonstrate a Swiftier way. Instead of a pair of arrays, make one array of pairs. Here, the pairs are custom struct instances. We declare a struct to pair fields and messages:

```
struct FieldMessage {
    let field : UITextField
    let message : String
}
```

Then we populate an array of pairs:

```
let fieldMessages : [FieldMessage] = [
    FieldMessage(field: field1, message: "You forgot the blorg"),
    FieldMessage(field: field2, message: "You forgot the zarg"),
    FieldMessage(field: field3, message: "You forgot the firth"),
]
```

The result is even simpler than before:

```
let message = fieldMessages.first {
    ($0.field.text ?? "").isEmpty
}?.message
// cool, eh?
if let message = message {
    showAlert(message)
} else {
    // no issues, valid, do the segue
}
```

Comment: An array of `(field, message)` tuples might make this easier to extend, and less error prone as there would be only one array to maintain.

Comment: @Cristik Hey, nice to hear from you. — I thought of that of course. Actually I thought of it first, but settled on two parallel arrays because  I wanted to keep things very simple for an obviously very beginning user. Feel free to give the array of tuples (or even a struct!) as an alternative.

Comment: Fair point, @matt, I'm thinking that if they are a beginner maybe it would be good to find out about other basic data types of Swift. A new answer that gives the same solution but with a different data type doesn't qualify worth adding, in my opinion, so I'll search for other questions to answer :)

Comment: @Cristik Well, I might come back to this later and give a more structured alternative then

Comment: Would `$0.field.text?.isEmpty ?? true` be faster (marginally) than instantiating an empty string for every message in `fieldMessages`? Or are empty strings somehow reused efficiently?

Comment: @Daniel I doubt there's any speed difference, but yours is probably more idiomatic.